# SQL CASE / WHEN evaluating to two possible values

Tags: sql

I have a list of items, Each item will have one of two options A or B. If the item has both options then A will always have a recipe of S (Standard) and B will always have a recipe of O (optional), However if there is ONLY the option B then B will have a recipe of S. I am a novice and can not begin to think on how to write this.

- Item__Option__Recipe
- 1____A______S
- 1____B______O
- 2____B______S
- 3____A______S
- 3____B______O
- 4____A______S
- 5____A______S
- 6____B______S

Comment: We need more information. Table structure, example data, attempted query, expected outcome...

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So `A` will always be `S` and `B` will be `S` unless there is an `A` and then it will be `O`?  If that's the logic then this should work:

```
SELECT
    A.Item,
    A.Option,
    CASE 
    WHEN Option = 'A' THEN 'S'   // A will always be S
    WHEN Option = `B` 
        CASE
        WHEN EXISTS(SELECT null FROM table WHERE Item = A.Item AND Option = 'A')
            THEN 'O'
        ELSE 'S'
        END
    END AS Recipe
 FROM table
```

Comment: I like your solution better and am going to change my code to match this. I actually got it to work by assigning a value of 1 to A and 2 to B and then summing that column by Item. So if there is an option B with a value of 3 that meant there has to be an A so it gets a recipe of O other wise the B would have a value of 2 which means no A so a recipe of S

Answer (score 0):

This assumes SQL Server syntax (for the table variable) but otherwise uses fairly standard (for these days) [Common Table Expressions](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) and a [`ROW_NUMBER()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx):

```
declare @t table (Item int,[Option] char(1))
insert into @t(Item,[Option]) values
(1,'A'),(1,'B'),
(2,'B'),
(3,'A'),(3,'B'),
(4,'A'),
(5,'A'),
(6,'B')

;With Recipes as (
    select 1 as rn,'S' as Recipe union all
    select 2,'O'
), Ordered as (
    select Item,[Option],
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
            PARTITION BY Item
            ORDER BY [Option]
        ) as rn
    from @t
)
select
    Item,[Option],Recipe
from
    Ordered o
        inner join
    Recipes r
        on
            o.rn = r.rn
order by Item,[Option]
```

And produces the result set you've shown.